# I get CSRF error when using enctype="multipart/form-data"

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

Whenever I add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my html form, I get `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token`

If I remove the enctype, it works

I'm sending the csrf code like this: `input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value= csrf_token)`

My Express file:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var csrf = require('csurf');


var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = function (app, passport) {

  // Static files middleware

  // set views path and default layout
  app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  // bodyParser should be above methodOverride
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(methodOverride(function (req, res) {
    if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
      // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
      var method = req.body._method;
      delete req.body._method;
      return method;
    }
  }));

  // cookieParser should be above session
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(cookieSession({ secret: 'secret' }));

  // use passport session
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  // connect flash for flash messages - should be declared after sessions

  // adds CSRF support
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    app.use(csrf());

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      res.locals.csrf_token = req.csrfToken();
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

My form:

```
form(action="/adminfruta/criarproduto" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post")
        input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value= csrf_token)
        .tipo Tipo do Produto
        
        input(type="radio", value="cesta", name="type", id="cesta", checked="checked")
        label.radio(for="cesta") Cesta
        input(type="radio", value="avulso", name="type", id="avulso")
        label.radio(for="avulso") Avulso
        
        label(for="name") Nome do Produto:
        input(type="text" name="name" id="name")
        label(for="code") Código da Cesta no sistema
        input(type="text" name="code" id="code")
        label(for="inventory") Estoque:
        input(type="number" name="inventory")
        label(for="description") Descrição:
        select(multiple="multiple" name="description" id="descricao")
            for item in itens
                option(value= item.id)= item.name

        label(for="quantities") Quantidade de cada item, de acordo com a ordem da lista (não da ordem que você selecionou) separado por virgulas
        input(type="text" name="quantities" id="quantities" placeholder="Exemplo: 3,1,1,4,2,6")

        .fotos
            .half
                .choose Escolha foto 1 (tamanho 250x250 px):
                input(type="file" name="foto1")
            .half
                .choose Escolha foto 2 (tamanho 250x250 px):
                input(type="file" name="foto2")
        
        .fotos
            .half
                label(for="price") Preço(em centavos):  
                input(type="number" name="price" placeholder="R$86,00  ficaria  8600")
            .half
                label(for="discount") Desconto (opcional): 
                input(type="number" name="discount")


        .tipo Categorias:
        ul.categories
            for category in categories
                li 
                    input(type="radio" value= category.id id= category.name name="category")
                    label(for= category.name) #{category.name}
        
        .tipo Produtos Relacionados:
        .relations
            select(id="related_products" name="related_products" multiple="multiple")
                for product in products
                    option(value= product.id)= product.name


        .tipo Adicionais:
        .relations

            select(id="addons" name="addons" multiple="multiple")
                for item in itens
                    option(value= item.id) #{item.name}
    
        button.button.save(type="submit") Criar Novo
```

My routes file

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multer= require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

var s3 = new aws.S3({/*params: {Bucket: 'frutacor'}*/});

// var upload = multer({ dest: 'public/img/users/' });
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'frutacor',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    }
  })
});

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.post('/adminfruta/criarproduto', admin.verifyAdmin, upload.fields([
    {name: 'foto1', maxCount: 1},
    {name: 'foto2', maxCount: 1}]), admin.createProduct);
}
```

And finally the admin.js file

```
exports.createProduct = function(req, res){
  var product = new Product(makeProduct(req.body, req.files));
  product.save();
  return res.render('admin/index');
};

var makeProduct = function(product, photos){
  product.photos.push(photos.foto1[0].location);
  product.photos.push(photos.foto2[0].location);
  return product;
};
```

Also, as for dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"async": "1.3.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.4.2",
"body-parser": "1.13.2",
"compression": "1.5.1",
"connect-flash": "0.1.1",
"connect-mongo": "0.8.1",
"cookie-parser": "1.3.5",
"cookie-session": "1.2.0",
"csurf": "1.9.0",
"easyimage": "^2.1.0",
"express": "4.13.1",
"express-session": "1.11.3",
"jade": "^1.11.0",
"method-override": "2.3.3",
"morgan": "1.6.1",
"multer": "^1.1.0",
"multer-s3": "^2.3.2",
"passport": "0.2.2",
"passport-local": "1.0.0",
"sha1": "^1.1.1",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"view-helpers": "0.1.5",
}
```

I thought the reason was multer, but then I changed multer version and stopped using it as a global middleware, and I'm still getting this error.

Note: It works if I change the action to include a "?_csrf=#{csrfToken}" after my URL, but I wanted a cleaner solution, if there's one.

Comment: Can you share the form code and the function code that receives the upload? I have the same things and are working properly.

Comment: @danilodeveloper, I added everything I thought could be usefull, but to keep moving, I'm using ?_csrf=#{csrfToken} at the URL until I can figure it out, but I removed it from the copy paste I posted here

Comment: Hey @iagowp, we need to test some cases here, 1 - try to add an `id` in you input like this `input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" id="_csrf" value= csrf_token)`. 2 - remove the space between the `value=` and `csrf_token` like this `input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" id="_csrf" value=csrf_token)`

Comment: And where do you create your routes in the express file? I'm asking this because you must call your `CSRF support` function AFTER express.session() but BEFORE app.router, inside of app.configure().

Comment: @iagowp Any Solution found to this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I ended up putting "?_csrf=#{csrfToken}" at the URL. Its not pretty, but it works

Answer (score 10):

make form like this

```
<form method="post" action="/?_csrf=<%=csrfToken%>"
```

and remove this

```
input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value= csrf_token)
```

Comment: If someone don't want to pass token in Url then can pass token in header as well.

https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#value

Answer (score 0):

`form(action="/adminfruta/criarproduto/?_csrf=<%=csrfToken%>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post")`

and your form must contaion this too

`input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value= csrf_token)`