# csrf token is invalid when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, multer

i am trying to upload a file in nodejs with authentication. When i try to upload the file with form with enctype is multipart/form-data. it shows a error csrf Token is invalid

```
<form action="/createtest/question" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
      <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

there is anyother way to fix this

Comment: Is the token just not being populated and just missing? Is it not matching? Do you have a reproducible example? Tough to troubleshoot without more detail sorry.

Comment: @ChrisW. i send the same post request without enctype="multipart/form-data" and file input it works fine, no the token is not missing

Comment: Oooooh, sounds like perhaps then you just need to attach the token as an action query param [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271815/i-get-csrf-error-when-using-enctype-multipart-form-data) instead if you do see the value getting attached correctly on that hidden input, then you can just get rid of the hidden input altogether.

Comment: @ChrisW. if i did like that when console.log the req.body in post request it shows file as object